# Kubernetes Load Balancer EKS SSL termination issues

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-elb, openwhisk

I'm trying to setup SSL termination for my EKS loadbalancer on an Apache Openwhisk deployment

```
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 50m
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: http
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: <arn>
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: https-api
  creationTimestamp: "2020-03-17T19:06:28Z"
  labels:
    app: owdev-openwhisk
    chart: openwhisk-0.2.1
    heritage: Helm
    name: owdev-nginx
    release: owdev
  name: owdev-nginx
  namespace: openwhisk
  resourceVersion: "43288"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/openwhisk/services/owdev-nginx
  uid: 679858cf-6882-11ea-8746-02f532cfa957
spec:
  clusterIP: <ip>
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ports:
  - name: http
    nodePort: 31858
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  - name: https-api
    nodePort: 32653
    port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 443
  selector:
    name: owdev-nginx
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: LoadBalancer
```

The service looks like this when deployed. With this configuration when I visit the endpoint in my browser I get:

```
400 Bad Request
The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port
```

but internally:

`curl -k -v https://owdev-nginx`

works fine.

If I then swap the targetPort of https-api to http, the external endpoint works, but the internal one has a similar error.

Any suggestions as to what to tweak to get both external and internal(certificate ignored) requests flowing through it?

I appreciate this is similar to the Common Pitfalls section here: https://kubernetes-on-aws.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide/tls-termination.html is there a way around it?

Answer (score -2):

The reason you are seeing this error is due to an easily fixed configuration issue. When the client tries to access your site via **HTTP**, over port **80**, the request is redirected to **HTTPS**, over port **443**. However, nginx is expecting the original request to arrive using **SSL** over port **443**.

Please let me know if it helps.

Similar problem: [bad-request](https://www.linode.com/community/questions/17826/400-bad-request-the-plain-http-request-was-sent-to-https-port-nginx).